# Unable to type text inside of material UI TextField

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have a button whose onclick opens up a material UI Dialog which contains a TextField. However, I can't click into the TextField to enter anything. Also, when I click on my button to open the Dialog, I get the error "findDOMNode is deprecated in StrictMode". Seems like that shouldn't affect the functionality based on other answers though.

Everything works normal if I change it to a div containing a normal input field, so it seems like a Material UI problem.

```
const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
const [body, setBody] = useState("");
const [errors, setErrors] = useState({});


const handleOpen = () => {
    setOpen(true);
};

const handleClose = () => {
    props.clearErrors();
    setOpen(false);
    setErrors({});
};

const handleChange = (e) => {
    setBody(e.target.value);
};

const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    props.newPost({ body: body });
};

const { UI: { loading }} = props;

    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <button onClick={handleOpen}>
          <AddIcon />
        </button>
        <Dialog
          open={open}
          onClose={handleClose}
          fullWidth
          maxWidth="sm">
          <button onClick={handleClose}>
            <CloseIcon />
          </button>
          <DialogTitle>Create a new post</DialogTitle>
          <DialogContent>
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
              <TextField
                name="body"
                type="text"
                multiline
                rows="3"
                onChange={handleChange}
                fullWidth
              />
              <button
                type="submit"
                variant="contained"
                color="primary"
              >
                Submit
                {loading && (
                  <CircularProgress/>
                )}
              </button>
            </form>
          </DialogContent>
        </Dialog>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
}
```

Comment: I'd suggest you probably have some conflicting CSS. At least I've experienced problems similar to what you're describing due to that. Try inspecting the CSS on the relevant element(s) and see if you can find some stylings imposed by your own CSS which may be responsible.

Comment: Unfortunately this component currently has no style sheet :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should work. Do some styles, add label, placeholder etc.

check the [working demo here](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-textfield-issue-fix-ps2pl?file=/demo.js) and see the code

**Code snippet**

```js
<React.Fragment>
      <button onClick={handleOpen}>Add</button>

      <Dialog open={open} onClose={handleClose} fullWidth maxWidth="sm">
        <button onClick={handleClose}>X</button>
        <DialogTitle>Create a new post</DialogTitle>
        <DialogContent>
          <form className={classes.root} onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <TextField
              name="body"
              label="Enter some text"
              multiline
              rows="3"
              onChange={handleChange}
              fullWidth
              placeholder="placeholder"
            />
            <button type="submit" variant="contained" color="primary">
              Submit
              {false && <CircularProgress />}
            </button>
          </form>
        </DialogContent>
      </Dialog>
    </React.Fragment>
```

**Style**

```js
const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  root: {
    "& > *": {
      margin: theme.spacing(1),
      width: "50ch"
    }
  }
}));
```

Comment: Yup, you're right. Completely missed the bottom portion of the box since it was all scrunched. Thanks for the help.

Comment: awesome. . glad to hear that... could you please consider to accept the answer and upvote it..